# Debowerifying Ember causes error

Tags: ember.js, gulp, browserify

I have installed ember as a bower component:
`bower install ember`

The `debowerify` transform is applied like so:

`var debowerify = require('debowerify');
      browserify().
      .transform(debowerify)
     .require('./bower_components/ember/ember.js')
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('vendor.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));`

When I run the above as a gulp task, it shows me the error:

```
    [07:38:56] Starting 'browserify'...
    [07:38:56] Running 'bundle'...

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: Cannot find module '../package.json' from 'app_root/bower_components/ember'
    at app_root/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:43:25
    at load (app_root/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:61:43)
    at app_root/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:67:22
    at app_root/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:21:47
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

```

On inspecting the ember.js file from the bower_components/ember directory, saw the following code:
`var packageVersion = require('../package.json').version;`

I am not sure how to resolve this issue and make debowerify play nice with Ember. I have created a repo that demonstrates the problem: https://github.com/saravanak/ember-debowerify

Comment: Having same issue using grunt-browserify-bower...